# a triggers question in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am kind of new to triggers and cant figure it out how to resolve this.

After insert a new row on a specicfic table it should influence other tables aswell.

So if I add(insert) an order on a table which includes 3 quantity, I want to be 3 less In_stock in another table(column)... thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming some column and table names (order table column name : quantity and product_id as the key uniquely used to identify an order) 
.. this should do the job

```
create or replace trigger trg_update_available
   after insert on orders 
   for each row
begin
   update in_stock
      set quantity = quantity - :new.quantity
      where product_id = :new.product_id;
end;
/
```

**Note : the commit; will still be present in the code where you insert the order.**

Comment: thank you so much, I will check it as soon as possible, thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. If you think the answer is helpful/correct, make sure you vote it up/mark it as the right answer :)